# Is it appropriate to advertise for Area 51 in a username?

Tags: discussion, area-51, advertising

I know it's definitely not okay to try to place unsolicited advertisements for Area 51 proposals (or anything else for that matter) in questions, answers, and comments. But what about a username, say "Area51BasketWeaving"? I'd really rather not see advertisements while trying to read real posts, but at the same time I don't want to stop people from picking their usernames.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks, I searched for a bit but managed not to find that!